# finding the top-level widget on a non-activewindow in qt

Tags: qt

I'm trying to find the top-level widget on a non-active window. But I do not want to use QApplication::topLevelAt() method.
I have a main window and several child widget's of main window's central widget. Is it possible to distinguish whether one of the child widget is on top of other childs?

Sami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QObject::children()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qobject.html#children) lists the children of a given object.  For `QWidget`s, the children are drawn in order of the list, which means that you can get the top-most (last-drawn) child with the following code:

```
QWidget *topmost_p = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(parent_p->children().last());
```

Be aware that the above code may fail if the parent has no children.